# pv: Change Prefix on the Fly

Tags: command-line, unix, pipe

To me `pv` is really handy some times. However, I was wondering if it was possible to change the prefix on the fly.

I mean usually I have something like

```
in.sh | pv -btrcN "Watch that work!!1!" | out.sh
```

I understand that I can't poke around in the memory of `pv`, but is it possible to use something like a hook inside the NAME-string?

In these examples the expressions are evaluated at the time `pv` starts:

```
in.sh | pv -btrcN "Watch that $var work!!1!" | out.sh
in.sh | pv -btrcN "Watch that `ls -1 | wc -l` work!!1!" | out.sh
```

What I want is to have `pv` evaluate NAME every time it prints the progress information. Is that possible? Maybe with some really dirty tinkering? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible because pv *isn't* evaluating NAME in the first place.

*Your shell* is evaluating the `$var` and `` `cmd` `` expressions before it runs any command.

So the only way this could be done is by extending pv's code to teach it to expand variables – either on its own or by calling the shell for help. (Then you'd use `pv -N "\$var"` to make the shell pass the $var unaltered.) This likely wouldn't help performance.

Comment: And there really is no deep down way in Unix to change NAME from the outside? Do I really have to change the source first?

Comment: @sjngm: Other than using a debugger or similar tool to directly modify the memory of a running `pv` process? No. It's one of those features that [don't exist by default](http://web.archive.org/web/20070609020513/blog.ryjones.org/2005/07/12/Product+Development.aspx).